# JavaScript ReferenceError being thrown on variable that is never referenced

Tags: javascript, templates, referenceerror

I'm making an HTML Templating Engine.

The program goes through the HTML, and finds all instances of {{ }}. It then goes through all the keys in our countroller, and replaces instances of variable names with a reference to the controller.

For example, if my controller is `{name:"grody"}` and my HTML has `{{name}}`, my program will do the following would replace that with `{{ctrl['name']}}`.

Then the program goes through and will use `eval()` on all the expressions to evaluate them.

So something like `{{name + " joe"}}` --> `{{ctrl['name'] + " joe"}}` --> `grody joe`

The error I'm getting is a ReferenceError, obviously happening within the `eval` of the function. This ReferenceError is only occurring when there is more than one variable, and it will throw an error on the first variable.

For example, if the template is `{{name}} is {{age}} years old}}` it will get a ReferenceError on name.

However, if you make the name a string, so something like `"na+me":"grody"` in the controller will cause a ReferenceError: na is not defined.

This is the code:

```js
function template(str, ctrl) {
  var exp = str.match(/[^{{]+(?=\}})/g).map(function(x) {
    return x.replace("}}", "")
  })
  for (var i = 0; i < exp.length; i++) {
    for (var prop in ctrl) {

      //console.log("propSearch:", prop.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&'))

      var evalExp = exp[i].replace(new RegExp(prop.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&'), "g"), "ctrl['" + prop + "']")
      str = str.replace(new RegExp("{{" + exp[i].replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&') + "}}", "g"), eval(evalExp))

      //console.log(prop)
      //console.log("exp[i]:", exp[i])
      //console.log("evalExp:", evalExp)
      //console.log("search:", exp[i].replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&'))
      //console.log("eval:", eval(evalExp))
      //console.log("str", str)

      evalExp = ""
    }
  }
  return str
}
```

Comment: If you click on the `<>` snippet editor button, you can create a [mcve]

Comment: Most likely your regular expressions not doing what you think

Answer (score 1):

I think you're making this a lot more complicated than it needs to be. I don't really understand why all those regular expressions and replaces are necessary. Here's a function that accomplishes what you're looking for:

```
const mustache = /\{\{(\w+)\}\}/g;

function template(str, ctrl) {
    return str.replace(mustache, (match, key) => ctrl[key]);
};
```

It's pretty rudimentary (it can only handle primitive string keys, but not expressions), but you can work on the callback passed to `.replace()` to make it smarter.